# How do you write the names under the chemicals?

Tags: chemistry, mhchem, annotations

I am fairly new to the mhchem environment. I want to write and equation such as in the figure. I can write the equation with no issues, I am just not sure how to add the names such as 'acid' or 'reducing agent' etc under the terms respectively.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Please add the mhchem code for this reaction (in the form of a small compilable document), that would make it easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The [mhchem manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) gives this example.

```
\ce{Zn^2+
  <=>[+ 2OH-][+ 2H+]
  $\underset{\text{amphoteres Hydroxid}}{\ce{Zn(OH)2 v}}$
  <=>[+ 2OH-][+ 2H+]
  $\underset{\text{Hydroxozikat}}{\ce{[Zn(OH)4]^2-}}$
}
```

[image]

Side-note: `Fe^{+2}` is an old notation that should not be used any more.

Comment: '\text' don't work for multiple lines, better use '\parbox' , like: $\underset{\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering{reducting \\ agent}}}{\ce{H+}}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution. I build a top aligned tabular where the first row is typeset inside `\ce` in normal size, but the other rows are in `\scriptsize`.

Since `\ce` scans for `\\`, you can't use it in the description, but `\tabularnewline` works as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\ck}[2]{% “compound kind”
  \begingroup\scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\normalsize \strut\ce{#1} \\ #2 \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\ce{
  \ck{8H+}{acid} +
  \ck{2e-}{reducing \tabularnewline agent} +
  \ck{Fe3O4}{oxide} ->
  \ck{3Fe^{+2}}{metal ions \tabularnewline in solution} +
  4H2O
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can do it similarly with `chemformula` that has already something to this purpose (see section 10 in the manual).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand{\stack}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\ch{
  !(\strut acid)( 8 H^+ ) +
  !(\stack{reducing \\ agent})( 2 e^- ) +
  !(\strut oxide)( Fe3 O4 ) ->
  !(\stack{metal ions \tabularnewline in solution})( 3 Fe^{+2} ) +
  4 H2 O
}

\end{document}
```

The `\strut` is necessary to get proper vertical alignment in the various names; `\stack` already adds it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question about annotating reactants in a chemical equation brought my method of doing that to mind. I started using the `mhchem` package (still use it indirectly when publishing pages in Mediawiki), but soon switched to the set of packages provided by Clemens Niederberger. In the answer of egreg one of those is already mentioned: `chemformula`.
To achieve the annotation of reactants in a chemical equation I use the `\chemname` macro form the `chemfig` package. To ensure correct representation of charges the `\pch[] \mch[]` macros from the `chemmacros` package can be used. `chemmacros` internally uses the notations from the (standalone) package `chemformula`, so there is no need to load that package separately.
`chemfig` uses the macro `\chemnameinit{}` to align the annotations correctly underneath the reactants.

An slightly annotated and stepwise MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,text={17cm,26cm}]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    Result using \verb|\chemname{}| in a chemfig reaction environment: \\
    
    \schemestart
        \chemname{\ch{8 H\pch[]}}{\small acid} \+{1em,1em,}
        \chemname{\ch{2 \el}}{\small reducing \\agent} \+{1em,1em,}
        \chemname{\ch{Fe3O4}}{\small oxide} \space 
        \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)[,0.8]
        \chemname{\ch{3 Fe\pch[2]}}{\small metal ions \\in solution} \+{1em,1em,}
        \ch{4 H2O}
    \schemestop 

\vspace{24pt}

Adding \verb|\chemnameinit\{ch{Fe3O4}}| aligns the annotations correctly: \\

    \chemnameinit{\ch{Fe3O4}}
    \schemestart
        \chemname{\ch{8 H\pch[]\aq{}}}{\small acid} \+{1ex,1ex,}
        \chemname{\ch{2 \el}}{\small reducing \\agent} \+{1ex,1ex,}
        \chemname{\ch{Fe3O4}\sld{}}{\small oxide} \space 
        \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)[,0.8]
        \chemname{\ch{3 Fe\pch[2]\aq{}}}{\small metal ions \\in solution} \+{1ex,1ex,}
        \chemname{\ch{4 H2O\lqd{}}}{\small solvent}
    \schemestop 
    \chemnameinit{}

\medskip
{\footnotesize \textbf{NB:} Phases are usually ommited from redox reaction schemes, but in this case they amplify the annotations used in this reduction equation.}

\vspace{24pt}

An example in line with the given reduction reaction using \verb|\chemnameinit{<largest reactant>}| in an oxidation reaction of an organic compound: \\

\setchemfig{bond style={line width=1pt},atom sep=2.1em,}

    \chemnameinit{\chemfig{H_3C-CH_2-C([1,1.1]=O)([7,1.1]-OH)}}
    \schemestart
        \chemname{\chemfig{H_3C-CH_2-CH_2-OH}}{\small propane-1-ol} \+{1ex,1ex,} \ch{H2O} % or \chemfig{H_2O} 
        \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)[,0.8]
        \chemname{\chemfig{H_3C-CH_2-C([1,1.1]=O)([7,1.1]-OH)}}{\small propanoic acid}
        \+{1ex,1ex,} \ch{4 \el} \+{1ex,1ex,} \ch{4 H\pch[]}
    \schemestop
    \chemnameinit{}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]